# Not able to fetch more than 15k rows from BQ table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have standalone Java application, which i am using to fetch data from BQ table in the form of CSV file. My BQ table has more than 50k rows. My Java application is not able to read more than 15k rows into CSV file. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get more than 128MB of data unless you're storing the result in destination table. Perhaps you should save the result in destination table and then to call Export class which will produce a CSV file in Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please direct me to the export class sample code in Java. I am trying get table data in BQ which is more than 128MB in CSV format using Java code. Are you saying i should call export class to download the CSV to GCS bucket. How do i call export class in Java to download csv file in GCS bucket?

Comment: You'll need to call [Jobs: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) and specify the [extract](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.extract) as your configuration type.  Here is the relevant [JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/). Here is the example of how to [read and write files from Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/using-cloud-storage) in Java.